# CKEditor dialogue can't close with IE11

Tags: civimail

When sending an email and if I insert a link or insert an image, I can't close the dialog when using IE11.

This works perfectly with IE9, Firefox and chrome browsers.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: I have run into this as well. It seems either related to the old CKEditor version used by CiviCRM, or the way it is integrated. Using the CKEditor in Drupal via the wysiwyg module partially resolves the issue, but we had issues with it in form popups.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid this is a known bug (at least by me), which I reported a while ago at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14860. I think it is related to the CKEditor version, and to the CKEditor upstream bug http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10604.

Comment: Update: Coleman says this ought to be fixed in 4.7 as part of https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16354.

Answer (score 2):

It's a known bug in CKEditor, which should be fixed in CiviCRM 4.7 as part of a [general overhaul of wysiwyg editors](http://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16354).